# Find and remove duplicate installation of composer

Tags: macos, composer-php

Recently I noticed that Composer has released version 2.0.x. I have composer installed through Homebrew, so I ran `homebrew update` and `homebrew upgrade` today. When I run `composer --version`, it still reports Composer 1.10.15 2020-10-13 15:59:09. When I run `brew list composer` it reports /usr/local/Cellar/composer/2.0.7/bin/composer. I'm assuming that I must have another version of Composer that is loading before the Homebrew version does, although I don't remember ever installing composer without Homebrew on this computer.

On macOS (10.15.7), how can I find out if, and where, I have another installation of Composer? And once I find it, is there a stable way to get rid of it and use the Homebrew version of Composer (2.0.7) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out where the `composer` is that is being used when you call `composer --version` by running

```sh
which composer
```

If it's installed at something like `/usr/local/bin/composer`, you can navigate to that directory and delete it. `rm -r composer` should do the trick.

After this you can uninstall and reinstall compose through brew using

```
brew remove composer -f
brew install composer
```

Try running `composer --version` again, if you've got the correct one, great!